# Full height responsive logo as much as header in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have this bootstrap theme-header from laravel auth:

```
<body id="app-layout" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="background-color:white;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>


                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    <p>NameOfBrand</p>
                    </a>

                </div>
                 ...
          </div>
      </nav>
```

I want to add my logo after the `<!-- Branding Image -->`

```
<img  class="navbar-brand" src="images/logoName.svg"></img>
```

But the result, is that logo is so small so it can be recognized even if it is in vector format.

[image]

My question how to make the logo within the header to be the same height as the header is, or at least make it big enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your logo's specific height:

```
.navbar-brand {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
```

or use percentages: http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/2551/

Comment: Slight verification, If I do so and rise the values the header rises up in height also with the logo itself. And there is kind of margin-bottom in the header-top which the logo can get higher.

Comment: Updated answer with a fiddle, check it.

Comment: But how I can make this image responsive whatever I zoom or not?

Comment: Strange thing with pixels works amazing but with percentage no. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: You may have to set a `height` in pixels for your navbar, for percentages to work.

Comment: but bootstrap doesn't set it automatically a certain height for navbar, or it sets in percentage?